# Simplify radical expression (a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following expansions:

$\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$ and $a>b>0$
Obviously we can simplify it further by hand $\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}$, but Mathematica doesn't know how to simplify it, I have tried several methods, but nothing worked.

```
FullSimplify[(a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b], a > b > 0, 
   ComplexityFunction -> #] & /@ {LeafCount, ByteCount, StringLength@*ToString}
```

Comment: What's puzzling here is that the target expression has a lower `LeafCount`, `ByteCount`, and `StringLength` than the original expression.  (26 vs. 19, 744 vs. 536, and 81 vs. 26 respectively.)  You would think that this would induce Mathematica to return it in at least one of the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = (a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2 // Factor])/Sqrt[a + b] // PowerExpand // Apart

(*Sqrt[a + b] - Sqrt[a - b]*)
```

Answer (score 6):

We can cherry pick a custom `ComplexityFunction` that rewards positive exponents:

```
posPowerComplexity[expr_] := LeafCount[expr] - 5Count[expr, Power[_, _?Positive], ∞]

FullSimplify[(a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b], a > b > 0, 
 ComplexityFunction -> posPowerComplexity]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[a + b] - Sqrt[a - b]
> ```

Comment: Nice, but changing that magic number  `5`  breaks the solution, so it looks like it's a bit of a gamble finding what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Agreed $\,\,\,\,$

Comment: how would a complexity function "same as before, but avoid roots in denominator" look like? on that note, how does one even access default complexity function?

Comment: The default complexity function can be seen [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html#677378510). It's essentially just `LeafCount` that also takes into account length of exact numeric quantities. A low level implementation is available through the undocumented symbol ``Simplify`SimplifyCount``.

Answer (score 5):

How about this

```
(a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b] // 
    Apart // 
    PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}] & // 
    Simplify

(*   -Sqrt[a - b] + Sqrt[a + b]   *)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem consists in the following: `PowerExpand[Sqrt[x*y]]` works, but `PowerExpand[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]]` doesn't. So

```
Expand[FullSimplify[PowerExpand[
FullSimplify[(a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b] /. {a -> x + y, b -> x - y}, 
 Assumptions -> x + y > x - y > 0]]] /. {x -> (a + b)/2,  y -> (a - b)/2}]
```

> `-Sqrt[a - b] + Sqrt[a + b]`

Comment: So does `Expand[FullSimplify[
   PowerExpand[
    FullSimplify[(a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b] /. {a -> x + y,
        b -> x - y}]]] /. {x -> (a + b)/2, y -> (a - b)/2}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = (a + b - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/Sqrt[a + b];

MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, a + b -> Sqrt[a + b]*Hold@Sqrt[a + b]] &, expr, 
   2] // Simplify[#, a > b > 0] & // ReleaseHold

(*   -Sqrt[a - b] + Sqrt[a + b]   *)
```

Have fun!